# Concept of bounded and well ordered sets

Tags: real-numbers

Why we can't say $]1,2]$ has a Minimum? 
Is it because we use this assertion only in the context of a partial order or total order which are not strict?

The Well-Ordering-Theorem says that every set can be well-ordered. A set X is well-ordered by a strict total order if every non-empty subset of X has a least element under the ordering.

And the Concept of Minimum is based on boundedness. A subset of a partially ordered set X is called bounded if it has both an upper and a lower bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are going to discuss the minimum of $(1,2]$ or sets like it in this context, we would do well the specify with respect to which ordering. In the case of the usual total ordering $\le $ on $\mathbf{R}$, it's fairly easy to see that no minimal element in $(1,2]$ can exist. Suppose that $1+\varepsilon$ were a minimal element in $(1,2]$. Then $1+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\in (1,2]$ and $1+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<1+\varepsilon$, contradicting minimality of $1+\varepsilon$.

It's worth noting that the Well-Ordering Theorem only provides the *existence* of an ordering with respect to which a given set $X$ is well-ordered. This may not coincide with a pre-existing order that the set $X$ may have been equipped with.

Comment: Thx, my questions was about the fact, that the usual total order in R does't fits the assumptions for the orders in the "well ordering theorem", as u said "...case of the usual total ordering...". Thats why (1,2] has no minimum in this case, right?

Comment: The point is that the total order provided by the well-ordering theorem is distinct from the standard ordering on $\mathbf{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing the well-ordering theorem where you shouldn't. That theorem is applicable if you already have a set, but you don't have the ordering on it yet. The theorem then claims that a well ordering on that set exists.

On $(1,2]$ we cannot use that theorem because we are already *given* ordering $\le$, which is the usual ordering of real numbers. That ordering is not a well ordering, and there are certain subsets (such as all of $(1,2]$) that don't have minimum. There is, certainly, *another* ordering on $(1,2]$, which will be well ordering ... but it's not $\le$, it is something else.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have a minimum because the infimum of the set, which is $1$, is not contained in $\left]1,2\right]$.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question, which is about why the well-ordering theorem isn't applicable here.